# Integrating Python code into a Flutter app

Tags: python, flutter, artificial-intelligence

I want to run python code in my flutter code. My intention is to integrate AI related stuff in my flutter App without internet connection. Method channel can be a solution came in my head as the first thought. But possibly can't do that way. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can integrate Flutter and Python by using **Flutter-Python Starter Kit**

The Flutter-Python Starter Kit is an open-source project. It is a bundle of scripts and source files that automate a number of actions that would otherwise require developers to do them manually. It puts together established and well-maintained technologies, making them work together.

The starter kit consists of 3 main components:

- **prepare-sources.sh:** A script that installs dependencies, generates gRPC stubs from a .proto, creates Dart/Python scaffolding and copies files to the Flutter and Python project directories.
- **bundle-python.sh:** A script that creates a self-contained Python executable and bundles it as an asset in the Flutter project, updates the asset version.
- **templates:** A folder with ready-made Dart and Python files that solve many problems, such as starting a gRPC server on the Python side, extracting and launching standalone executables, firing up gRPC client channels, etc.

for more info follow this [link](https://dev.to/maximsaplin/integrating-flutter-all-6-platforms-and-python-a-comprehensive-guide-4ipo#:%7E:text=Enable%20the%20use%20of%20Python,for%20mobile%20and%20web%20platforms.)